# Any way to deploy Fuse project other than Fabric

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

I started using JBoss Fuse a while ago, for deploying my projects I use Fabric.

I want to know if there is any other way to deploy my projects.

Other questions: JBoss Fuse (6.2 which the version I use) is based on OSGI. What's the utility of OSGI? Is it necessary?

Comment: What kind of Fuse porject are you talking about? an OSGI bundle , a war file , a FAB?

Comment: my project is packaged as bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use fabric you can hot-deploy your project directly into the root OSGi container by placing it in the /deploy folder.

If you use the shell, you can manualy deploy your project using the osgi:install command.

OSGi is the core container technology in JBoss Fuse 6.2 . It's mandatory to deploy your project in the OSGi container

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in Fuse, but from what little experience I have, I would recommend to actually learn Fuse without Fabric first. This is especially true for version 6.2. I tried Fabric but ran into many issues and I think they working to making the latest Fabric and Fuse compatible.

Just deploy your projects using osgi:install/osgi:uninstall and it will make things easier.